# How to provide OperaWebDriver on c# use Selenium WebDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, opera

How to provide OperaWebDriver on c# use Selenium WebDriver

```
  IWebDriver aDriver = new OperaDriver("path_to_operadriver.exe);
```

I have exception :

> System.InvalidOperationException : unknown error: cannot find Opera
>   binary   (Driver info: OperaDriver=0.2.0 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got to download [opera chromium driver](https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/releases).

Here's a snippet how it should work:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.opera();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setBinary("/path/to/opera");
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
```

Comment: May be you know how to provide NUnit tests report,usuing Visual Studio and NUnit framwork?

Answer (score 1):

Using setBinary gives me an error. I am able to resolve it by using this:
`options.BinaryLocation = @"/path/to/opera";`

Similarly for chrome as well.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20698220)

Comment: I don't know what do you mean exactly. I exactly had the same problem as asked in the question. I am able to solve using the method mentioned above.